# How to get current state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return {
           name: "",
           ingredients: "" 
        }
    },
handleSubmit: function() {
        var newRecipe = {
            name: this.state.name,
            ingredients: this.state.ingredients
        };
        this.props.handleAdd(newRecipe);
        this.handleClose();
    },
handleNameChange: function () {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        });
    },
    handleIngredientsChange: function () {
        this.setState({
            ingredients: event.target.value
        });
    },
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange}></input>
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <textarea value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={this.handleIngredientsChange}></textarea>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

**SITUATION:**

`this.state.name` is `undefined`. Why ?

It must have something to do with my current implementation of setState ?

I am learning React, so there may be a few obvious mistakes.

Comment: where you checking state value?

Comment: @Ved Code updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is missing `event` argument for `handleNameChange` and `handleIngredientsChange` methods :

```
handleNameChange: function () {
  this.setState({
    name: event.target.value
  });
},
```

Try changing it to:

```
handleNameChange: function (event) {
  this.setState({
    name: event.target.value
  });
},
```

because in your initial method, `event` is undefined, so it sets your state to `undefined` too.

The same is available for this `handleIngredientsChange`, change it to:

```
handleIngredientsChange: function (event) {
  this.setState({
    ingredients: event.target.value
  });
},
```

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻    GRRR

Answer (score 2):

1. Store state into a ref(useRef)
2. Then define ref.current = state_name
   ref.current always get current updated state